# Treeview for svn commits

Tags: git, svn, graph, tree

Is there a tool for svn which can build similar tree/graph structures of commits as i.e. the TortoiseGit log or (in textual representation) the `git log` command? [image: Git branch/merge sample]
<sub>(source: [adamfranco.com](http://www.adamfranco.com/files/2010/12/git-merge-no-ff.png))</sub>

Comment: See also [this queston](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104961/how-can-i-view-the-version-tree-for-a-file-in-svn-which-shows-the-merges-from-br), which isn't a duplicate but provides some useful supporting information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any tool addressing this issue, so I finally use `git svn` and keep the git `repo` in sync with the `SVN`.

Answer (score 3):

There's a sort of such tree in TortoiseSVN, but it shows only branches created from trunk.

From what I know - SVN does not have sufficient info to know if the merge process occurred. The merge is consists of updating the file **on client side** and then committing it to SVN. This way repository does not knows if those changes are from merge or been introduced by hand, or result of other actions. In daily use you can combine both operations (merge and then edit file again) before finally committing to repository - that makes the whole thing impossible to solve.

Since branching is a distinct function performed on a repository server - it can be built in such tree. If SVN had distinct merge function, performed on repository server, then such graphs would be easy to build, as merge and update were separate operations.

Comment: The 'revision graph' is only slightly similar to what I'm searching for.

Comment: Thats the closest thing I know of in SVN. I will be happy to see my answer proved wrong (with working examples).

Comment: There are at least the commits in the merge-info. Something should be possible with this detail? Maybe even with comparing commit message or other "dirty hacks"?